# PDF is not downloading on Chrome localhost and Safari

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

**PDFHelper.cs**

```
 byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length",                     bytes.Length.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.pdf");
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

**LoginFactory.js**

```
        factory.getPDFReport = function (data) {
        var headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf;' };
        var url = hostUrl + '/ReportsController/PDFReports';
        return $http.post(url, data, headers).then(
           function (results) {
               return results;`**enter code here**`
           });
    }
```

This is my code but it is not working for Chrome localhost and Safari browsers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ASP.NET offers `Response.TransmitFile` for downloading a file. The following code will do the trick.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file_name.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(file_path);
Response.End();
```

**UPDATE**

if you have problems with safari browser then change `AppendHeader` to `SetHeader` in the code.

```
Response.SetHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file_name.pdf");
```

Comment: thanks it is working...but it is directly downloading i want it open in the new tab...

Comment: Where you have wrote this part of your code? (eg: button onclick event)

Comment: usually adding `target="_blank"` on your asp.net object will trigger the event in a new window.